# Как в Android ОС поменять дату создания .mp4 файлов?

Tags: android, файлы, файловая-система

На андроид-эмуляторе Bluestacks 4 в папке лежит много видео-файлов (рандом кол-во) с такими именами: **1.mp4  , 2.mp4 , 3.mp4 ... 99999.mp4**

Сначала нужно **удалить в них все доступные для удаления (exif-метаданные)** и далее **изменить дату создания этих файлов**, чтоб последний файл (99999.mp4) - стал с самой старой датой создания , а первый файл (1.mp4) - стал с первой датой создания.

Или нужна тулза\скрипт (по крайней мере в адроид прилке Total Commander в ручной переименовке это работает) :
Переименовываем эти файлы по очереди, то есть начиная с последнего (999999a.mp4) , далее переименовываем предпоследний, и так далее  ...заканчиваем переименование на первом файле  (файл 1.mp4)
Чтоб получились имена файлов так: 1a.mp4    2a.mp4  3a.mp4 ... 999999a.mp4

С помощью такого переименования в нужном порядке - даты создания файлов будут идти по очереди, 999999a.mp4 - будет самый старый , 1a.mp4 - будет самый новый. Но в этом случае exif- метаданные не знаю как удалить.

**Подскажите как это реализовать?**

Comment: Копируете файл - копия (она же новый файл) получает текущую дату создания и изменения, оригинал удаляете. Так по порядку со всеми. Про exif не знаю - не сталкивался.

Answer (score 1):

build.gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
```

Меняем exif

```
InputStream in = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(in);
exif.setDateTime(new Date().getTime());// или для очистки exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, null);
// для всех доступных
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_..., null);
exif.saveAttributes();
```

Получить все не null атрибуты нельзя. Если очень нужно, то через рефлексию exif.mAttributes содержит массив хэшмэпов, которые можно почистить и надеяться, что при сохранении все будет как нужно.

Дальше копирование/переименование файлов в зависимости от вашей логики. Лучше бы конечно сначала список файлов составить а то может оказаться, что 100.mp4 будет раньше 11.mp4, отсортировать, подобрать им новые имена, потом сохранять и видимо с некоторой задержкой...

Comment: Наверное можно и не копировать сами файлы. Судя по [этому](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-mainline/fs/utimes.c) там д.б. реализован [utimes()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html)

Comment: @avp utime, utimes - change file last access and modification times. Дату создания все-таки поменять не получится кажется. Кроме того, в Сишные функции врядли хотелось бы лезть, я думаю. Копировать точно не надо, да, exif.saveAttributes и так перезапишет файлы, судя по реализации, через создание временных файлов. Переименование тоже больше технический момент - банально `File.renameTo()` или `Path.move()`, с логикой главное разобраться...

Comment: @YuraIvanov, при перезаписи и переименовании дата создания сохраняется, а ТС хочет изменить. Так что копировать всё же надо.

Comment: @woesss да, вы правы. Но чтобы избежать лишних копирований можно что-то придумать, например код saveAttributes натравить на новое имя файла, а старый файл удалять. В общем это зависит от желания и необходимости...